# How to break for loop from inside of inner class in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

As we know according to [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#java), firebase listeners works asynchronous thread.
I tried this listeners inside for loop.
my code like.

```
switch ("condition") {
    case "condition1":
        for (int i=0;i<myVillz.size();i++)
        {
            UserRef.child(myList.get(i)).child(VISIBLE).child(key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                    {
                        someMethodToStopForLoop();
                        **amIable=true;**
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
        }
        break;

    default:
        **amIable=false;**
        break;
}
```

I want stop firebase loop whenever datasnapshot will exist. And making some boolean amIable=true

Comment: This is not possible.  You can't break out of a simple for loop from within an asynchronous callback.

Comment: "simple for loop"...means Is there any advance loop such a doing this task ?

Comment: Yes, Kotlin coroutines.

Comment: Please suggest in java